# How can I render 3 partial views with the data on selecting an item in the listbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my project, I want to extract all the fields, facilities, tanks from db based on BlockID. For each category like fields, facilities, tanks I prepared a partial view. When I run the solution, I am able to retrieve only the fields related to block in the dropdown control. I want to display all the fields' data related to that block in the partialview and also fill them in the dropdown. I  could see the data in .cshtml files, but I am unable to render them on UI. Please help me.

// Controller Action

---

```
public PartialViewResult FieldsOfBlock(long blockid)
    {
        FacilityModel bkvm = new FacilityModel();
        var fields = bkvm.FieldList(blockid);  // comes from backend
        ViewBag.Data = fields;
        return PartialView("_PartialField");
    }





   // PartialView
```

---

```
@model List<ABC.Models.Field>

@{
  var data = ViewBag.Data as List<ABC.Models.Field>;
}

 <div class="table-responsive col-lg-12 margintop20">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-hover"        id="myTableDataField">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Field Name</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @{ 
                    if(data.Count!=0)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in data)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.Name</td>

                    </tr>
                    }
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have the drop down trigger 3 AJAX calls and replace each bit in the DOM in the success callbacks.

Comment: I tried many times in different ways. I could see the data in the .cshtml files with the help of debugger. But when the partial views are rendered on the browsers, all the columns and rows are empty. What could be the reason?